# React make rest call when button clicked by textbox value and show in table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, spring-boot

I have two endpoints `http://localhost:8080/persons` to get all persons and `http://localhost:8080/persons/id` to get persons by id. I need to create a React page with a textbox and button to search by ID or all if the textbox is empty, and show results in a table. I am very new in React and I have the following code but is not working and I am not sure why, could you please help me?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale-1">
    <script src="http://www.jimsproch.com/react/future/react.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.jimsproch.com/react/future/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.jimsproch.com/react/babel-browser.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.16.2/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-table/6.5.3/react-table.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-table/6.5.3/react-table.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/babel">
    class TableExp extends React.Component {
        constructor () {
            super();

            this.state = {
                tableData: [{
                    id: '',
                    name: '',
                }],
                personId: '',
            };
        }

        handleChange = event => {
          this.setState({ personId: event.target.value });
        }

        handleSubmit = event => {
          event.preventDefault();

            axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/persons/${this.state.personId}`, {
                responseType: 'json'
            }).then(response => {
                this.setState({ tableData: response.data });
            });
        }

        render () {
            const { tableData } = this.state.tableData;

            return (
              <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                  <label>
                    Person ID:
                    <input type="text" name="id" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                  </label>
                  <button type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
                <ReactTable.default
                      data={tableData}
                      columns={[
                          {
                              Header: 'Person',
                              columns: [
                                  {
                                      Header: 'ID',
                                      accessor: 'id',
                                  },
                                  {
                                      Header: 'Name',
                                      accessor: 'name',
                                  },
                              ],
                          },
                      ]}
                      defaultPageSize={10}
                      className="-striped -highlight"
                  />
                </div>
            );
        }
    };
    ReactDOM.render(<div><TableExp/></div>, document.getElementById("root"));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: I first was showing all persons as soons as I open the page and it worked fine:

```
class TableExp extends React.Component {
        constructor () {
            super();
            this.state = {
                tableData: [{
                    id: '',
                    name: '',
                }],
            };
        }
        componentDidMount () {
            axios.get('http://localhost:8080/persons', {
                responseType: 'json'
            }).then(response => {
                this.setState({ tableData: response.data });
            });
        }
        render () {
            const { tableData } = this.state;
            return (<ReactTable.default
                            data={tableData}
                            columns={[
                                {
                                    Header: 'Person',
                                    columns: [
                                        {
                                            Header: 'ID',
                                            accessor: 'id',
                                        },
                                        {
                                            Header: 'Name',
                                            accessor: 'name',
                                        },
                                    ],
                                },
                            ]}
                            defaultPageSize={10}
                            className="-striped -highlight"
                    />
            );
        }
    };
    ReactDOM.render(<div><TableExp/></div>, document.getElementById("root"));class TableExp extends React.Component {
        constructor () {
            super();
            this.state = {
                tableData: [{
                    id: '',
                    name: '',
                }],
            };
        }
        componentDidMount () {
            axios.get('http://localhost:8080/persons', {
                responseType: 'json'
            }).then(response => {
                this.setState({ tableData: response.data });
            });
        }
        render () {
            const { tableData } = this.state;
            return (<ReactTable.default
                            data={tableData}
                            columns={[
                                {
                                    Header: 'Person',
                                    columns: [
                                        {
                                            Header: 'ID',
                                            accessor: 'id',
                                        },
                                        {
                                            Header: 'Name',
                                            accessor: 'name',
                                        },
                                    ],
                                },
                            ]}
                            defaultPageSize={10}
                            className="-striped -highlight"
                    />
            );
        }
    };
    ReactDOM.render(<div><TableExp/></div>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

The API is in Spring Boot:

```
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("repository,factory")
@SpringBootApplication
public class PersonController {

    private PersonRepository PersonRepository;

    @Autowired
    public PersonController(PersonRepository PersonRepository) {
        this.PersonRepository = PersonRepository;
    }

    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping("/persons")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Person> getPersons() {
        return PersonRepository.getPersons();
    }

    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping("/persons/{id}")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Person> getPerson(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
        return PersonRepository.getPerson(id);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PersonController.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: `'http://localhost:8080/persons/${this.state.personId}'` should be `\`http://localhost:8080/persons/${this.state.personId}\``

Comment: Thanks, I changed it but is still not working

Comment: Ok I will check it out, but please check my edit in the question, I was first showing all persons without the button and textbox and it was working fine, so I was able to use the API without problem

Comment: Console is showing: "Submit Fired: "
"Change Fired: 1"
"Submit Fired: 1"

Comment: Again, We can't see your api unless you provide the code. And just because it works for `/persons` doesn't mean it works for `/persons/:id`. Depending on how you set up the API and the ordering of your endpoints, there can be issues. The console statements from the codepen are there to show you that the event handlers are working just fine, so the issue must be with the API call.

Comment: Ok, check again the edit in the question, the API is in Spring Boot, Person class is just a POJO and PersonRepository is a Spring component that uses a RestTemplate to get the Persons from another endpoint.

Comment: This is helpful. So the question involves the difference between what each endpoint returns. Your front-end code is expecting data to be an array of objects. I don't know, but you can find out, what type of JSON data structure does `PersonRepository.getPerson(id);` return to your front-end `axios` call?

Comment: It makes sense, but I just changed the `/persons/:id` to return an array of objects and is still not working. Besides the `/persons/` was returning an array since the beginning and was neither working.

Answer (score 0):

As whl said, you're using quote marks for a templet literal. Also can you explain what exactly isn't working? any errors?

Comment: I changed it but is still not working, the search button does nothing and the chrome console shows no error